# bootstrap horizontally align elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out why my button isn't aligned with the input field. I use bootstrap as example

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Search:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="search-id" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Required" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load();">Load</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply move the label outside of the flex-container:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
 <label>Search:</label>
<div class="row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="search-id" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Required" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load();">Load</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks i got it, but in my case I have to add more input fields. So what i did is just add a label for my button then i hide it while taking up the space

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Update markup

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">

  <p>Search</p>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-flex-end">

    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="form-group">

        <input type="text" name="name" id="search-id" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="load();">Load</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```